# How does contravariance work with Func delegate in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, generic-variance

I have the following piece of code where I am trying to write a generic validation rule for my domain objects. while doing so I have an issue to deal Func delegate supporting variance

```
public class Person { }
public class Employee : Person { }

internal interface IValidation<T> where T: Person  
{
     void AddValidationRule(Func<T,bool> predicateFunction);
}

internal class BaseValidation : IValidation<Person>
{
    void IValidation<Person>.RegisterValidationRules(Person person)
    {

    }
}

internal class EmployeeValidation : BaseValidation
{
    void RegisterValidation()
    {
        Func<Employee,bool> empPredicate = CheckJoiningDate;
        base.AddValidationRule(empPredicate);
    }

    bool CheckJoiningDate(Employee employee)
    {
        return employee.JoiningDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) ;
    }
}
```

With the above code in place, compiler gives an error message saying

> Compiler Error on line : base.AddValidationRule(empPredicate);
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<>Employee, bool>' to
>   'System.Func<>Person, bool>

I had referred to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd465122%28v%3dvs.100%29 but I still couldn't make the compiler to understand about the contravariance here,

Appreciate your help so I understand this better

Comment: you have missing code, I could not reproduce issue.

Comment: `Func<>` is indeed a *contravariant*, but you're trying to use it as a *covariant*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot convert from 'System.Func<>Employee, bool>' to 'System.Func<>Person, bool>

`base.AddValidationRule` requires a function that can operate on any `Person`. Your function can only operate on `Exployee` which is more restrictive. This is the wrong form of variance.

It is not shown here but likely `BaseValidation` implemented `IValidation<Person>`.

Likely, the best fix is to ensure that you inherit from `IValidation<Employee>`, possibly by making `BaseValidation` generic.

Would this work?

```
internal class BaseValidation<T> : IValidation<T>
{
    void IValidation<T>.RegisterValidationRules(T entity)
    {
    }
}

internal class EmployeeValidation : BaseValidation<Employee>
{
 //...
}
```

Comment: I have added Basevalidation. As you mentioned, I was trying to create a collection of rules which can be executed later. I understand the variance difference as explained by Eric, any idea how I could do this better?

Comment: @user824910 I have added a proposal.

Comment: ah! I missed the generic implementation part.. Thanks for helping me on this.

Answer (score 8):

You've mixed up covariance and contravariance.

With covariance, the generic type argument can be "smaller" than what is required.  That is, if we have:

```
Func<Mammal, Mammal> f1 = whatever;
Func<Mammal, Animal> f2 = f1;
```

Why does that work?  `Func` is *covariant* in its second parameter. `f2` is expecting a delegate that returns `Animal`. It got a delegate that returns a *smaller* type; there are fewer `Mammal`s than `Animal`s, so `Mammal` is *smaller*.

Think about why this works. When someone calls f2, they are expecting to get an animal back.  But if they are really calling f1, they still get an animal, because every mammal is an animal.

With covariance, the "size" of the generic type varies *in the same direction* as the size of the type argument. `Mammal` is smaller than `Animal`.  `Func<Mammal, Mammal>` is smaller than `Func<Mammal, Animal>`.  That's why it is "co" variance, co meaning "together".

Contravariance is the opposite, hence "contra", meaning "against".  With contravariance, the generic type argument can be bigger than expected:

```
 Func<Giraffe, Mammal> f3 = f1;
```

f3 expects a function that takes a giraffe; we have a function that takes a bigger type, mammal.  It's bigger because there are more mammals than giraffes. Contravariance says this is good, and that should make sense.  If someone calls f3 with a giraffe, it's OK if that is actually a call to f2, because f2 can take a giraffe; it can take any mammal.

You've mixed up covariance and contravariance; you're expecting that a contravariant parameter can be used in a covariant manner, which is wrong.  A function that takes employees cannot be converted to a function that takes persons, because you could pass a non-employee person to it.  A function that takes employees can be converted to a function that takes managers, because all managers are employees.

Comment: I suspect that variance will not fix his problem. `AddValidationRule` sounds like a collection of rules is built and later executed. It seems that rule set must use the exact type of the objects that will be passed in for validation. We will see when the OP responds.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for your quick brief. I'm still wondering why we cannot assign a function that takes employee to a function that takes person? assuming there are fewer employees than persons. similar to fewer Mamals than Animal. I am trying to get my understanding right as I am learning.

Comment: @usr you are right, I am trying to build a collection of rules to be executed later.

Comment: @user824910: Suppose that were legal. `Action<Dog> a1 = d => d.Bark(); Action<Animal> a2 = a1; a2(new Giraffe());` and we just made a giraffe bark. Obviously that program has to be wrong; which line is wrong?  The first line is clearly legal; barking is an action of dogs. The last line is clearly legal; you can pass a giraffe to an action that takes animals. Therefore it must be the second line that is illegal.

Comment: @user824910: Now do it the other way:  `Action<Dog> a1 = d => d.Bark(); Action<Poodle> a3 = a1; a3(new Poodle());` We just made a poodle bark; nothing wrong there. This program is legal.

Comment: @user824910: The *inputs* of a function can be made *smaller*; a function that takes people can take any employee. But they cannot be made *larger*; a function that takes only employees cannot take an arbitrary person because the function might depend on a property of employees that is not found in a non-employee.

Comment: @EricLippert so are we saying that the JoiningDate in Employee will be dependent on employee and hence it is not valid to make it as Person? If so, please advise the right way to achieve a generic validator functionality for all entity modelled

Comment: Offhand I do not know how to do that, sorry.